# Curl Problem, I just don't get it

Tags: php, curl

SOLVED: var_dump revealed that that the issue was of & and `&amp; .`

Also I would still like to know why curl fetched a page with missing divs. Would anyone be kind enough to explain ?

have been at this problem for 1.5hours now. Narrowed down to something that just doesn't make sense to me. Please help . I am fetching a page using curl.
The problem is that when the following code is used: 
 a lot of div tags from the navigation to the left are missing from the fetched page,

```
$pageToParse = "http://www.themarketgrocer.com.au{$arrayLeftBar[$i]} " ;
                ;
//fetch target page
$curlFetched = http_get($pageToParse, "http://www.google.com") ; //fetched using a curl function
echo $curlFetched['FILE'];
```

the value of $arrayLeftBar[$i] is fetched from an html page using simplehtmldom. as echoed:

```
"/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=37&Itemid=92"
```

HOWEVER if

```
$pageToParse = "http://www.themarketgrocer.com.au{$arrayLeftBar[$i]} " ;
```

is changed to : (basically manually appending the value of $arrayLeftBar[$i] )

```
$pageToParse = "http://www.themarketgrocer.com.au/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=37&Itemid=92" ;
```

then the complete page is fetched.

WHY ?? I have echoed the values and they are identical. What silly little thing am I missing?

Edit:
THis is how the $arrayLeftBar is being populated: I am pretty sure the problem is here . Coz if I manually create a simple array. Things work.

```
foreach ($sublevelLinks as $link)
{
    $arrayLeftBar[] = $link->href ;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure they're identical, and don't just look identical on a webpage? I.e. view source and see if it's & not &amp;, etc. You also have a trailing space in `$pageToParse`, your desired URL does not end in a space character.

Comment: You both are right. var_dump revealed that that the issue was of & and &amp; . Sigh... and big thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: var_dump revealed that that the issue was of & and & .
 html_entity_decode($arrayLeftBar[$i]) did the necessary conversion

Answer (score 0):

On the `$arrayLeftBar[$i]` value use [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

```
$query       = urldecode($arrayLeftBar[$i]);
$pageToParse = "http://www.themarketgrocer.com.au{$query}" ;
```

Comment: tried that , didn't work . html_entity_decode() did work though :)